# Single-Double quotes error in Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am run into trouble.If type in Single-Double quotes in search statement will raise up a error,My sql statement like this:

```
 SELECT UsersID,Sex,Age FROM dbo.UserBasicInfo WHERE 
       CONTAINS(PositionDesired,'"*"JAVA*"')
```

The error message:

Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near `'JAVA*'` in the full-text search condition `'"*"JAVA*"'`.

Assume that the result must contains Single-Double quotes like: `"JAVA"PHP"` How to do? 
Thanks !

Comment: Well should `"*"JAVA*"` be `"*JAVA*"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra embedded double quote:

```
CONTAINS(PositionDesired,'"*"JAVA*"') 
----------------------------^
```

This effectively terminates the string early, and SQL Server doesn't understand what that extra stuff is.

Should be (I think, not a full-text guru):

```
CONTAINS(PositionDesired,'"*JAVA*"')
```

However, I think that will eliminate the error, but not return the results you are after, since punctuation is ignored. You may have to use a combination of `CONTAINS` and `LIKE`, e.g.:

```
CONTAINS(PositionDesired,'JAVA')
  AND PositionDesired LIKE '%"JAVA"%'
```

Or for the new requirement you've added:

```
CONTAINS(PositionDesired,'JAVA PHP')
  AND PositionDesired LIKE '%"JAVA"PHP%"'
```

In the `LIKE` clause you don't have to worry about escaping or doubling-up the double quote, because it isn't a string delimiter there.

Hopefully the `CONTAINS` clause will filter results first, but even in a normal query there is no guarantee of short-circuiting or order of evaluation; I have no idea about a query with full-text and standard filters.

Comment: Assume that the result must contains Single-Double quotes like:

"JAVA"PHP"  How to do? Thanks

Comment: @user441222 [this KB article might also be useful](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246800) - it's old but much of these things in FTS haven't changed.

Comment: @user441222: The full-text search feature searches for words. I don't think you can search for punctuation like `"`.